# Delete all attachments at a time on a Particular Opportunity Record

Tags: opportunity, attachment, contentversion, contentdocument

I have to delete all attachments related to a particular Opportunity Record based on Id or Name. Currently, I am deleting them manually one by one.

Is there any workaround to delete all attachments at a time on a single record?

Some opportunities have more than 15-20 Attachments.

Comment: Are you using files? Or are they really just attachments?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script and execute it on developer console anonymous apex.

```
List<Attachment> listAttachments = [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = 'opportunityId'];
delete listAttachments;
```

**NB: I suggest you to test it on sandbox first and dummy record to ensure it is working as you expect.**

Comment: note you can do this in one statement `delete [SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId ='theOppoId'];`